# What are the limits of %z in Python datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, email

I am trying to parse [the mailing list of Apache Pig](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/). I use the following function while parsing the dates.

```
from datetime import datetime

def str_to_date(date_str):
    # First, remove the (UTC) type of parts at the end
    try:
        date_str = date_str[: date_str.index("(") - 1]
    except ValueError:
        pass

    # Then, try different date formats
    for date_format in [
        "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",
        "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %z",
        "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z",
        "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",
    ]:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    raise ValueError("No valid date format found for {}".format(date_str))
```

In the [201201.mbox](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201201.mbox), the following error raises:

```
ValueError: No valid date format found for Fri, 20 Jan 2012 16:31:14 +0580
```

When I inspect the mbox, I realized that it includes `Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2012 16:31:14 +0580` line. So, it does not match any of the date formats in the function but the problem is `+0580` should be "a 5-character string of the form +HHMM or -HHMM, where HH is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset hours, and MM is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset minutes" [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

According to the mbox, the offset of the mail date is `+0580`, which means plus 5 hours and 80 minutes. Isn't that wrong? Or, do I miss  something?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 60 minutes in an hour, so `MM` can't be more than 59. `+0580` should be `+0620`.

Comment: It seems like it to me.